# Why does grep constantly trigger the Windows warning bell?

Tags: windows, bash, windows-7, grep, cygwin

I'm running `bash` on Windows 7 with Cygwin, using `mintty` as a console. When I use `grep -b 5 -a 5` on a *very* large text file - 14GB, to be more precise - I find that every 3-4 seconds, it triggers a succession of Windows warning/information bells as grep is outputting to the console. I haven't experienced this before in my use of `bash` over the last few week, although this is also the first time I've outputted to the console in the way that `grep` does.

**What could be triggering this, and how can I get rid of it?**

Comment: Are you sure it is a pure text file?  The most common cause of the symptom you describe is printing from files that contain bell characters (control-G).

Comment: It was an `.lst` file that I converted to `.txt` by simply changing the file extension, but I'm 99% sure it contains plain text.

Comment: Tip: If you have a terminal output buffer with too many bells to tolerate and can't abort, you can (as an Administrator) `net stop beep` and then `net start beep`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the terminal is interpreting parts of the text as control characters. Are you sure the file contains just plain text? Mintty has a option to configure what the "bell" control character does; make sure the sound checkbox is unchecked.

Another solution would be to pipe the grep output to something that will filter away anything that is not a visible character in the ASCII range.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pipe your grep with:

```
| sed 's/\x7//g'
```

Beeps should disappear if they were caused by the bell character. You can also get rid of all non-printable characters with:

```
| sed 's/['$(printf '\\x%x' {0..31})']//g'
```

Comment: bell should be \x7 not \xb  http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/bell-ascii-code-7.html